# In Linux, given DirectMap4k, DirectMap2M, DirectMap4M, and DirectMap1G, why nr_hugepages?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

It seems that the kernel is using huge pages anyway, so why have a specific kernel parameter specifying the number of huge pages to keep in reserve?

After all `/proc/meminfo` displays [values for `DirectMap4K`, `DirectMap4M`, and `DirectMap1G` indicating the number of page table entries in existence for each size of page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204286/what-does-mean-by-hardwarecorrupted-directmap4k-directmap2m-fields-in-proc-m). So, clearly, pages larger than 4KiB are being used.

Why do `/proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages` and friends still even exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nr_hugepages` still exists because it is complementary to the other values you mention. The [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) has all the details, but basically, `/proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages` shows the number of persistent huge pages of the default size within the kernel’s huge page pool (whose size is shown by `HugePages_Total` in `/proc/meminfo`). `nr_hugepages` is an administrator-controlled setting, defined at boot using the `hugepages` kernel parameter, and/or at runtime by writing to `nr_hugepages` (as long as the system is capable of providing the requested number of huge pages).

The purpose of `nr_hugepages` is to make huge pages available *to userspace programs*, *via* `hugetlbfs` or shared memory or `mmap`. The number of pages allocated *via* `nr_hugepages` constitute a pool of huge pages reserved for this use; if the system’s resources permit, more huge pages may be available (up to the limit set by `nr_overcommit_hugepages`), but that’s not guaranteed. It is available on all platforms supporting huge pages. These pages are useful for programs which make large memory allocations, but they do introduce constraints — in particular they can’t be swapped out.

As mentioned in [what does mean by HardwareCorrupted, DirectMap4k, DirectMap2M fields in “/proc/meminfo” file of Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204286/86440), `DirectMap` is an x86-specific implementation detail. It measures the use of page maps for pages of various sizes, *by the kernel*; this shows how much the kernel has been able to map pages as huge pages of various sizes. This isn’t limited by `nr_hugepages`: even on a system with no huge pages in the huge page pool (for user space), the kernel will try to coalesce page mappings to reduce the TLB load (see `try_preserve_large_page` in [`pageattr.c`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c)).

Comment: I see, so it's largely orthogonal. Why would a userspace process want to do this? I suppose it isn't common, which is why overcommit and nr_hugepages is typically 0. But I can't come up with a clear use, even an uncommon one.

Comment: Some applications allocate large amounts of memory and benefit from huge pages: database management systems, the JVM, virtual machines... [The Debian wiki page on the topic](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages) has relevant pointers.

Comment: I also found a nice lwn article on the topic.

Comment: For posterity's sake, here's the link to the LWN article that's an overview of history lesson on huge page support in Linux in general: https://lwn.net/Articles/374424/

Comment: I read the kernel documentation, but it's full of how, not why.

Comment: This blog about Oracle's use of hugepages is also excellent: https://blogs.oracle.com/linuxkernel/linux-kernel-hugetlbfs-enhancements,-by-mike-kravetz