# What is using a 1G-byte page on my system?

Tags: memory

I have noticed that if I do `cat /proc/meminfo`

I get the following

```
…
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      662864 kB
DirectMap2M:     7643136 kB
DirectMap1G:     1048576 kB
```

It shows that one 1G-byte page has been allocated. However when I look at ksysguard, I see no process with more than 125M / 213M(rss) of memory.

How can I find out which process is using it?

---

## More info

```
#> cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
[always] madvise never
```

Comment: Probably explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068335/how-does-directmap1g-affect-the-number-of-hugepages

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov You think there is a kernel option set? Do you know what good it can do? Can I remove it? I will go look in the grub config.

Comment: Speaking frankly I've no clue at all. I also have a single 1GB page mapped and seemingly no applications which could have done that, so I thought maybe it's what the kernel reserves for itself by default. I don't use any boot flags or special kernel options.

Comment: In my case it's even more weird: `DirectMap1G:    52428800 kB` - and no applications using more than 200MB of RAM. Maybe it's due to `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_ALWAYS` being enabled here: *Enabling Transparent Hugepage always, can increase the memory footprint of applications without a guaranteed benefit but it will work automatically for all applications.* I believe it's the most likely explanation.

Comment: I have added some more info. @ArtemS.Tashkinov is there a way to set `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_ALWAYS`? I have found compilation option, and a write to `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` option (maybe I can do this in early boot).

Answer (score 4):

The `DirectMap` entries don’t reflect memory *use*, they reflect page maps, or page entries, for physical memory. `DirectMap1G` counts the amount of memory mapped using PUD-level page table mappings.

The mappings are set up during boot; see [`arch/x86/mm/init_64.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/mm/init_64.c) and look for `phys_pud_init` and `phys_p4d_init`. The sum of the values shown in `/proc/meminfo` for the various `DirectMap` entries should be similar to the total amount of physical RAM in your system, and the total will never vary, although the share will (for example, a PUD-level mapping can be split into PMD-level mappings, which will reduce the value shown in `DirectMap1G` and increase the value shown in `DirectMap2M`).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this fully answers the question, but it dose partly.

While investigating I accidentally re-booted. On restart I noticed `DirectMap1G` was not 5G-bytes. After realising that I had done nothing to the persistent configuration. I noticed that the total of the three page sizes added up to about the size of my RAM 8GB. I added it up properly and it was 8G9 (8.9G) [probably other memory mapped stuff: vRAM, and other hardware, the MMU does not only work with RAM]. I then started a big process, measured again, the total was still about 8G9 (it moved a bit). I opened another process, measured, opened another … it always is summing to 8G9.

Answer (score 0):

DirectMap is an indicator, related to kernel space. You seem to consider it being like hugepages, which can be used by userspace.

I quote:

> DirectMap is x86-specific and gives an indication of the TLB load (Translation Lookaside Buffer), not memory use: it counts the number of pages mapped as 4KB pages, 2MB/4MB pages, and 1GB pages if supported and used.

[meaning of hardware corrupted, directmap fields in /proc/mem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204286/what-does-mean-by-hardwarecorrupted-directmap4k-directmap2m-fields-in-proc-m)

Comment: I think they are the same thing. But huge pages is a user-space interface. I now don't thing that it is a process that has `malloc`ed it, or a hugh-pages reservation. I think it is an artefact of strange reporting: free memory is included. As I write this, I am wondering why it needs to add up to total physical memory. Are these not virtual memory?